In a TeX file that has no section, chapter etc, if we label a Figure, the ref does not show a number, what is the best solution?
Consider a TeX file that does not have any section, chapter etc. It is just a bunch of text and a figure. The figure has a \label and inside the text \ref is used. I can see that label is fine and ref is recognizing the label because in TeXStudio when you hover your mouse on the \ref it shows a short message showing the location of the corresponding label. However when you compile the file, there is no text on the location of ref in the PDF. If I add a dummy \section before them, then I see the number 1 in the location of ref. So instead of "see Figure." I will get "see Figure 1.". But I don't want that section in this TeX file. What is a proper and standard solution here?

put the \label after or in the \caption.

As Ulrike mentions, it is the \caption that provides the number \label can refer to. If you're using something like \begin{figure}\label{myfig} it will just point to that last "referable" thing, which is is usually a section or similar. So in your case there it nothing for it to refer to.

I hope that you can now also see why we always ask for code, not some essay. We need to see exactly what you are doing.

@UlrikeFischer and daleif thanks. Yes, you're right. After reading your comments I remembered that I knew this before but I had forgotten it. The label should be after the caption. If you put it as an answer I confirm it, it may helps next visitors to the question.
